# AlarmManger doesn't work

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

When I use Calendar it does not work  !

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2016, 11 , 28);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 54, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() , pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Your `Calendar` is set for next month. `Calendar.NOVEMBER == 10`. You might double-check the day, too.

Comment: I changed it , still not working !

Comment: Does the alarm work at all? What happens if you pass `0` instead of `cal.getTimeInMillis()` in `alarmManager.set()`?

Comment: now it works , I've removed  the app then reinstall it again . Thanks !